# MySQL 8 Json document merge data from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I've JSON documents in multiple rows  as

Row #1

```
{ 
    "data": {
            "level": 1,
            "name": "xyz",
            "property": "value",
            "children": [
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-1"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Row #2

```
{
    "data": {
            "children": [
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-2"
                },
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-3"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Row #3

```
{
    "data": {
            "children": [
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-4"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

I want to use MySQL 8 JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE in such a way so I get the result

```
{ 
    "data": {
            "level": 1,
            "name": "xyz",
            "property": "value",
            "children": [
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-1"
                },
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-2"
                },
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-3"
                },
                {
                    "level": 2,
                    "name": "xyz-4"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

I've tried

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(
    '{ "data": { "level": 1, "name": "xyz", "property": "value", "children": [ { "level": 2, "name": "xyz-1" } ] } }',
    '{ "data": { "children": [ { "level": 2, "name": "xyz-2" }, { "level": 2, "name": "xyz-3" } ] } }',
    '{ "data": { "children": [ { "level": 2, "name": "xyz-4" } ] } }'
) as json;
```

But I want to SELECT the JSON data from the table and merge it, something like

[Not working]

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(a.data_json) from 
    (SELECT data_json FROM data_table
    WHERE name = 'abc') as a
```

The error message is 
Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE'

Answer (score 0):

One of the many options you can evaluate and use is CTE (Common Table Expressions) - [13.2.13 WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE `cte` AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS `row`,
    `data_json`
  FROM
    `data_table`
  WHERE
    `id` = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    `cte`.`row` + 1 AS `row`,
    JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(`cte`.`data_json`, `data_table`.`data_json`) AS `data_json`
  FROM
    `data_table`, `cte`
  WHERE
    `data_table`.`id` = `cte`.`row` + 1
)
SELECT
  JSON_PRETTY(`data_json`)
FROM
  `cte`
ORDER BY
  `row` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7049992a5a728cb1594788a042dbdd0b).